# Is a basis of 3 orthogonal vectors the same as the columns for a 3x3 rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Good afternoon,

This is a simple question that I cannot seem to be able to find an answer for.

If I have 3 unit 3D vectors which are orthogonal to each other.

Vector U, Vector V, and Vector W.

```
W = U x V
U = V x W
V = W x U
```

The rotation matrix that indicates the rotation from the coordinate system where those vectors are defined to the new coordinate system defined by those vectors is just:

```
[ Ux  Vx  Wx ]
[ Uy  Vy  Wy ]
[ Uz  Vz  Wz ]
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors, so ...

Comment: You answered my question with a question. Am I correct or incorrect? Images of the basis vectors are what?

Comment: The wikipedia page on change of basis only covers 2D rotation from basis vectors, it doesnt mention 3x3 matrices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis

Comment: Ever hear of the Socratic method? This is a general property of *all* linear transformations. Whether or not it’s a rotation and the number of dimensions is irrelevant. If the basis vectors $\mathbf e_i$ are mapped to the vectors $\mathbf v_i$, respectively, then the transformation matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_1&\mathbf v_2&\cdots&\mathbf v_n\end{bmatrix}$. Knowing this, you ought to be able to answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Found it,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions

Obscured by definition of Formalisms